# Filename parameter that could contain special characters

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to get the filename as a parameter and find that file within a directory in my code. Since the filename could contain spaces, I've enclosed it in double quotes as well, but it still fails when the filename has spaces and '-' or any other character like '_'.
How to handle such filenames?

```
echo $(filename)

paths=$(find $(Build.SourcesDirectory) -name "$(filename)")
```

For filename : `Staging - test.json`

Error:

```
Error opening file "/home/vsts/work/1/s/Team-EAP/Staging" 
ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/vsts/work/1/s/Team-EAP/Staging'
```

Editing to add more details:
The reason am referring the filename within braces () is because it is passed on as a parameter to the REST call within Azure DevOps, and in Azure DevOps we have to use the brackets to refer to such parameters.

Comment: `echo $(filename)` is wrong. (you are not doing *command-substitution* on the filename). You can use braces, e.g. `${filename}`. If `find` returns more than a single filename, your `paths` will not work. Correct your `(), {}` issue first. (or just double-quote it, e.g. `"$filename"`).

Comment: This one works fine: find . -iname "${filename}"

Comment: Apologies for not adding the details of the usage of () in the filename. Using "${filename}" is not working because I have to use () to refer it.

Comment: *and in Azure DevOps we have to use the brackets to refer to such parameters.* then this question has nothing to do with bash.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the output of find command to a bash array like this:

```
echo $(filename)

paths=()
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'; do
    paths+=("$REPLY")
done < <(find $(Build.SourcesDirectory) -name "$(filename)" -print0)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will need that when the path will return multiple values. But currently when the filename has special characters, it fails. Is there a way around it?

Comment: Please try passing the value of filename pattern like this: filename="Staging*". So, the find command should list all the file with the matching pattern and add those entries to the paths array irrespective of spaces or special characters in the filename.